# wp_list_categories add class

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So what I need to do, is when I list `wp_list_categories` I need to check an ID with each category ID listed on `wp_list_categories` and if that statement is true add a class.Something like this:

`if($foo = $category_id) echo '<li class="active">Category name</li>';` Is this possible?

//Short brief

I need something like this because I list the categories in the sidebar and also I display the first post from that category, so I need to mark that category as active when I do this and I do all of this in a page template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by passign an argument `current_category`

Comment: I know but I can't at this moment